# Upgrade mongoose from 5 to 6 Value of type 'typeof ObjectId' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, types

I recently upgraded mongodb from `3.5.4` to `4.1.4` and mongoose from `5.12.10` to `6.0.12` as I am using **typescript** `4.4.4` and **ts-node** `10.4.0` in my project I get a type error ***Value of type 'typeof ObjectId' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?*** when using this line of code `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` I uninstalled and removed the @types/mongoose from the project as the new version mongoose has its own type and removed globally also but still I get the same error.

Despite the fact that the mongoose team tagged this issue [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9608) a bug and later tagged it as resolved, I continue to receive this error.

Note: using the new keyword to resolve this issue makes some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [migration guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#typescript-changes). In v6, `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` is now a class and you must use `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` instead `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` in TypeScript. You can read more at https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10960.